# Error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token (", makes no sense to me

Tags: jquery

My code:

```
<script>

(function() {
    var box = $('div.box'),

    $('button').on('click', function(){
        box.animate({
            'fontSize': '+=5',
            'width': '+=300'
        }, 500, 'swing', function(){}
        });
    });

})(); 


</script>
```

The code does not work for me, however it does for the tutorial I am watching on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dnk3pbW6s6Y

If someone could help me solve this, it would be great.

Comment: `var box = $('div.box');`

Answer (score 0):

Remove the empty function from the end of animate and place the code in a document ready function:

```
  $(function() {
        var box = $('div.box');

        $('button').on('click', function(){
            box.animate({
                'fontSize': '+=5',
                'width': '+=300'
            }, 500, 'swing');
        });

    });
```

jsfiddle exemple:https://jsfiddle.net/c4stn135/

Comment: Tell the OP what you have changed and why. Not only the code.

Comment: This code has syntax error and doesn't look any different than question. Provide explanation instead of expecting people to *"spot the difference"*